# Single NTP server on isolate network

Tags: linux, time, ntp

I have two linux machines (A and B) on an isolated network. They must be time-synchronized. Machine A is powered intermittently and must serve the time, as it is connected to an authoritative time source (GPS). Machine B is only powered if machine A is powered, but it is an embedded linux device and its power state will change frequently. Neither machine has access to other systems. It's a closed network.

I understand that this is quite a tall order for NTP, as NTP usually expects to have contact with several servers. I'm having trouble getting this to work properly on Machine B. Machine A synchs to the GPS just fine, and machine B can reach machine A and even do time queries, but Machine A is not trusted (perhaps by itself?). After a solid hour of machine A being up, this suddenly changed and machine B worked. However, when machine A went down (and thus machine B), machine B is once again unable to find a good time synch.

Here's some ntpdate info. Please note that even when machine A's stratum is 1, the operation fails with the same output at the end.

```
10.10.10.1: Server dropped: strata too high
server 10.10.10.1, port 123
stratum 16, precision -19, leap 11, trust 000
refid [10.10.10.1], delay 0.02614, dispersion 0.00000
transmitted 4, in filter 4
reference time:    00000000.00000000  Thu, Feb  7 2036  6:28:16.000
originate timestamp: d3a9bdc4.27ebb350  Thu, Jul 12 2012 21:19:00.155
transmit timestamp:  bc17c803.b42dfffe  Sat, Jan  1 2000  0:25:39.703
filter delay:  0.02625  0.02614  0.02618  0.02625 
         0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000 
filter offset: 39544160 39544160 39544160 39544160
         0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
delay 0.02614, dispersion 0.00000
offset 395441600.451568

 1 Jan 00:25:39 ntpdate[677]: no server suitable for synchronization found
```

My guess is that machine A just doesn't trust itself for serving time. After 51 minutes (may have happened earlier, I don't know) of uptime and having its clock synch'd to GPS, machine A started to serve time correctly, and machine B picked it up. I need this to happen earlier. Like, within seconds if possible.

With the following configs (and a lot of waiting), it eventually succeeds.

Machine A ntp.conf:

```
server 127.127.28.0 prefer true minpoll 4 maxpoll 4
fudge 127.127.28.0 stratum 1 time1 0.420 refid GPS
```

Machine B ntp.conf:

```
server 10.10.10.1 prefer true minpoll 4 maxpoll 4
```

ntpq -c peers on Machine B without good time fix:

```
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 10.10.10.1   .STEP.          16 u    9   16    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
```

ntp1 -c peers on Machine B with good time fix:

```
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
*10.10.10.1   SHM(0)           2 u    7   16   17    0.669    2.597   1.808
```

So, now the question becomes: how do I make Machine A trust itself quickly?

Some debug output from Machine A before and after machine B decides that Machine A is good enough to use..

before..

```
~ # ntpq -c rv
associd=0 status=c418 leap_alarm, sync_uhf_radio, 1 event, no_sys_peer,
version="ntpd 4.2.6p4@1.2324 Fri Feb 24 15:01:45 UTC 2012 (1)",
processor="armv7l", system="Linux/2.6.35.14", leap=11, stratum=2,
precision=-19, rootdelay=0.000, rootdisp=44.537, refid=SHM(0),
reftime=d3ab0053.43b44780  Fri, Jul 13 2012 20:15:15.264,
clock=d3ab0062.e7e03154  Fri, Jul 13 2012 20:15:30.905, peer=34819, tc=4,
mintc=3, offset=0.000, frequency=0.000, sys_jitter=3.853,
clk_jitter=36.492, clk_wander=0.000
```

after...

```
~ # ntpq -c rv
associd=0 status=0415 leap_none, sync_uhf_radio, 1 event, clock_sync,
version="ntpd 4.2.6p4@1.2324 Fri Feb 24 15:01:45 UTC 2012 (1)",
processor="armv7l", system="Linux/2.6.35.14", leap=00, stratum=2,
precision=-19, rootdelay=0.000, rootdisp=41.278, refid=SHM(0),
reftime=d3ab0063.43b37856  Fri, Jul 13 2012 20:15:31.264,
clock=d3ab006d.9ee53ec2  Fri, Jul 13 2012 20:15:41.620, peer=34819, tc=4,
mintc=3, offset=0.000, frequency=43.896, sys_jitter=0.762,
clk_jitter=36.953, clk_wander=0.000
```

Comment: Could we see the `ntp.conf` files and output from `ntpq -p` when machine B is NOT getting good time from machine A?  It could be marking machine A as a false ticker or something.  When machine B isn't trusting machine A, is machine A synchronized with the GPS? (Output of `ntpstat` on machine A.)

Comment: I've heard that [chrony](http://chrony.tuxfamily.org/) is more suitable for this application. "If your computer connects to the 'net for 5 minutes once a day (or something like that), or you turn your (Linux v2.0) computer off when you're not using it, or you want to use NTP on an isolated network with no hardware clocks in sight, chrony will work much better for you."

Comment: @AaronCopley I can post those in a few (10 or 12) hours. Machine A becomes sychronized to the GPS within a minute of booting Machine B has problems synching to machine A for quite a long period of time.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Thanks. I'll look into it, but I'm a little reluctant to change much beyond configurations if I can help it. It's a chore to  cross-build anything for Machine B at this time.

Comment: @AaronCopley Updated.

Comment: Perhaps this is an issue due to the driftfile not being created?

Answer (score 9):

NTP should work fine.  Look at some of the options for fast synchronization on start-up.   Look at the `burst` and `iburst` options for the system B.  Look at the `true` option for the GPS clock source.

Consider using the hardware clock as a backup time source on both systems.  Set a higher stratum system B. Something like the following should work:

```
server  127.127.1.0
fudge   127.127.1.0 stratum 8
```

Watch the output of `ntpq -c peers` to see when you get a trusted clock source.  Normally `ntp` wants a number of responses from a trusted time source before it trusts it.  This is indicated by the first character on each line.

While NTP likes more sources, any odd number of time sources within one stratum level should work well.  As you only have two servers and a GPS clock the priority (stratum) of the sources should increase from GPS, clock on server A, clock on server B.  Increasing the stratum between each by three or four levels will ensure priorities are respected.

EDIT: If you have the busybox NTP server on server A, it may be worthwhile installing the full ntp server package.   Understanding what is happening with server A should go a long way to solving your problem.  You will need at least one trusted time source there before server B should trust it.  If `ntpq -c peers` doesn't work, then you can try `ntpdc peers`.  Both these commands allow you to query other hosts.  A `peerstats` log could also be useful.

On server B use ntpclient as documented the [busybox ntp howto](http://doolittle.icarus.com/ntpclient/HOWTO) to log what is happening on it

The clocks should be reasonably close to the correct time if the servers haven't been down for long.  If you need to sync the two systems, that should be sufficient.  The GPS will bring the time into sync with the real world eventually.

'ntpd -q' synchronizes quickly, but exits (ntpdate behaviour).  It needs to be followed by an `ntpd` command without the quit option to have continuous synchronization.

EDIT2: I check my server and found one of the servers was off by a second.  While fixing this I played with the settings. `iburst` gets a server trusted very quickly.  `true` ensured the clock driver was trusted if there weren't multiple other trusted sources.  The clock took a little more than a minute before it was locally trusted and could be trusted remotely.

When testing you should be able to restart the `ntpd` process once it is synchronized and test how fast settings work.  In the above case Server B may need to be restarted to test how fast it synchronizes.  When monitoring `ntpd` changes I use a line like:

```
while ntpq -c peers localhost; do sleep 10; done
```

The hostname and sleep time are adjusted as require.  In some cases I chain two or more `ntpq` command lines in the loop. When doing so I use an echo and/or date command to provide an indication of where sets of data change.

Comment: Adding burst to the conf file did not improve the situation. Each of these machines is a busybox machine, and the "-c" option is unknown to ntpq. Also, the clocks cannot be trust on these devices until they are synched with the GPS. Just a limitation of the systems. Thanks.

Comment: I actually made one small mistake, I already had the full version of ntpd running on Machine A. Machine B is the only one running the BusyBox version (and if I had a way to build programs for it, I'd do the same there). Eventually, everything works. I think it's a sever trust problem. Could you give some insight to my edits? Thanks.

Comment: Also, if you get a chance to edit your answer again, could you @ me so the system notifies me? Thanks.

Comment: @SanJacinto I have added a second edit with results from my system.  I don't have the busybox ntpd client so I can't vouch for the results with it.  I would try adding both `true` and `iburst` to server B.

Comment: +1 from me for your effort, but it's not solving my problem. A solution I've found (and please suggest something else if you wish and I'll try it) is to kill ntpd on machine A after it synchs to the GPS, and then restart it. This seems to let machine B synch to machine A within seconds. My guess is that a 42-year jump in time on Machine A (always boots from the Epoch) is making it nervous about sharing its time, but when it starts and the clock is already set, it's as though the clock wasn't far off to being with, so minor adjustments make it feel good about sharing its time. I did allow ntp..

Comment: to create a driftfile and I can see its contents (44.025 after running all weekend), but this alone was not enough to get a fast synch. The restarting of ntp seems to be the key.

Comment: If system A doesn't have a clock it will have problems. Try running it with -q before starting to serve time.  It will quit as soon as it syncs, and can then be restarted to serve time.  It should be a simple edit to the init.d script.